# Retrieve Course Material Files that uploaded in Android API

Tags: android, google-classroom

Is there anyway to retrieve Course Material Files that shared? I need to get the google drive link.

Comment: If you just want to get the courseWork Material, then you can use the [Method: courses.courseWork.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/get) to get it. If this file is already in your Drive, then [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) of the Google Drive can help you.

Comment: I wanted to get files that shared by the Teacher, not the students. I have found the solution by doing this: courses.get.getCourseMaterialSets